# Google Maps AutoComplete Not working after setting up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have looked at most of the questions on SO surrounding the topic of google maps autocomplete and have also looked at the docs. For some reason it seems like nothing is happening client side despite having the JS and HTML all set up. I have also looked into the developers console for errors and there are none.

Here is the included script tag I have:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
```

#### html

```
 <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">City</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="city" placeholder="San Francisco, Oakland, etc..">
      </div>
 </div>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('city');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I have no idea what to do from here. Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you get any errors in the **developer** tools console? (asked before the question was edited to include that information)

Comment: @JaromandaX There are no apparent errors.

Comment: your code works fine as is (as long as the script tag for `googleapis` is above the code you've posted - and with an appropriate API KEY) - as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dvb9vLdx/)

Comment: UGH I don't understand why it isn't working for me!

Comment: not even in the fiddle?

Comment: It works in fiddle but not in my code

Comment: then you've either used an invalid key, or have the code in the wrong "order" - either of which should be apparent from the console though

Answer (score 2):

Ahh I found out the error. I have this autocomplete input box in a bootstrap modal and the autocomplete options were hidden behind the modal since it has a natural z-axis. To resolve this I just added some simple css:

```
.pac-container {
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```